# When I send two emails on the same script using phpmailer, the second email gets send to both the first and second email address

Tags: php, phpmailer

Honestly, I have not tried anything.

the send email function is

```
function sendEmail($recName, $recEmail, $sub, $MsgToSend, $attachment = false, $replyTo = false){
        $mail = $GLOBALS['mail'];
        $mail->addAddress($recEmail, $recName);
        $mail->Subject = $sub;
        if($replyTo !== false && !preg_match('/^\s*$/', $replyTo)){
            $mail->addReplyTo($replyTo);
        }
        $mail->msgHTML($MsgToSend);

        $mail->AltBody = $mail->html2text($MsgToSend);
        if($attachment !== false && !preg_match('/^\s*$/', $attachment)){
            $mail->addAttachment($attachment);
        }
        
        if($mail->send()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the script

```
<?php

require_once("../../logic/functions.php");
require_once("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
require_once("sendEmails.php");


//all variables set here

$sql = "INSERT INTO employee(firstname, lastname, email, phone, address_one, address_two, emp_password, emp_type) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,'ordinary')";

$conn = makeConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$password = $conn->escape_string($password);
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $phone, $address_one, $address_two, $password);
if($stmt->execute()){
    //send an email to confirm email
    $email_hash = password_hash($email, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $id = base64_encode($conn->insert_id);

    $link = "http://localhost/lalalala/html/confirm-email/?k=".$email_hash."&i=".$id;
    $sub = "Confirm your email";
    $msg = "The first message";
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    sendEmail($firstname." ".$lastname, $email, $sub, $msg);

    //informing and admin
    $sql = "SELECT `firstname`, `lastname`, `email` FROM `employee` WHERE emp_type = 'super_admin'";
    $res=$conn->query($sql);
    if($res->num_rows > 0){
        $link = "http://localhost/lalalala/html/login.php";
        $res = $res->fetch_assoc();
        $admin_firstname = $res['firstname'];
        $admin_email  = $res['email'];
        $admin_lastname = $res['lastname'];

        $sub = "Approval for $firstname";
        $msg = "The second message";

        sendEmail($admin_firstname." ".$admin_lastname, $admin_email, $sub, $msg);
    }
    echo "yes";
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    exit;
    
}

echo "no";
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
exit;
```

As you can see, when I call sendEmail the first time, it sends the email to the user. Then it is to notify an administrator to approve the new user. However, the approval email gets sent to both the new user and the administrator. Surprisingly, the second sendEmail doesn't add the new user's email as a receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHPMailer instance remains in scope so it retains addresses between sends. Call `clearAddresses()` between sends to clear them.